# Is there a better and faster way to convert from Scipy condensed distance matrix to a Scipy sparse distance matrix under a threshold

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to calculate the euclidean distance between n-dimensional points, and then get a sparse distance matrix of all points where the distance is under a set threshold.

I've already got a method working, but it is too slow. For 12000 points in 3D, it takes about 8 seconds. The rest of the program runs in under a second, so this is the main bottleneck. This will be ran hundreds of times, so improving this step will increase performance by a large amount.

This is my current implementation.

```
def make_sparse_dm(points: np.array, thresh):
    n = points.shape[0]
    distance_matrix = 
        spatial.distance.squareform(spatial.distance.pdist(points))   
        # pairwise_distances(points)
    [i, j] = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(n))
    points_under_thresh = distance_matrix <= thresh
    i = i[points_under_thresh]
    j = j[points_under_thresh]
    v = distance_matrix[points_under_thresh]
    return sparse.coo_matrix((v, (i, j)), shape=(n, n)).tocsr()
```

The output is then fed into a library which is much faster when the input is in scipy sparse distance matrix form.

Comment: I wonder whether the `pdist` is the big time consumer, or creating the sparse matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj From my timings they are about the same, both taking about 4 seconds

Comment: `point_tree = spatial.cKDTree(points);
point_tree.sparse_distance_matrix(point_tree, thresh).tocsr()`
is a pithy way to write this, but it doesn't appear to be faster than `make_sparse_dm`.